# How to create a month over month new companies bar chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

Lets say I create an index in elasticsearch and import data

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "orders": {
      "properties": {
        "devices": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "location": {
          "type":"geo_point"
        },
        "time" : {
          "type":"date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        },
       "company" : {
         "type":"keyword"    
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is fairly simple to do in kibana is getting unique count of companies per month, which is fine, but not good enough to get a number of companies that had the first order in that month. Is this possible in kibana or timelion ? If not any idea how I should save data to elastic so I could get this number ? I am using Kibana 5.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a property type in index called sequence, which is the number of the sequential order, so if it is a first order I gave it 1, if second 2 and so on...
Mapping looks like this

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "orders": {
      "properties": {
        "devices": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "email": {
          "type":"keyword"
        },
        "company": {
          "type":"keyword"
        },
        "location": {
          "type":"geo_point"
        },
        "sequence":{
          "type":"integer"
        },
        "time": {
          "type":"date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So for this operation i choose Timelion which is cool and lets you calculate values. The formula for MoM % of new users is...

```
 (new users this month / cumulative users till previous month)
```

This look in timelion expression like this

```
.es(q=sequence:1,index=index,timefield=time,metric=cardinality:company)
.divide(.es(index=index,timefield=time,metric=cardinality:company,offset=-1M)
.cusum()).bars()
```

Note that this query is all one query I only cut it in 3 pieces for easier readibility. And i added bars() just for fun.